# How do I convert below query into codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
SELECT r.report_id,
       a.advertisement_title,
       COUNT(r.advertisement_id) AS total
FROM report r
JOIN advertisement a ON a.advertisement_id = r.advertisement_id
GROUP BY r.advertisement_id
```

Comment: this is not domywork.com you need to learn on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here in below how you can do it

```
$this->db->select('r.report_id,
       a.advertisement_title,
       COUNT(r.advertisement_id) AS total');
$this->db->from('report r');
$this->db->join('advertisement a','a.advertisement_id = r.advertisement_id');
$this->db->group_by('r.advertisement_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query('
SELECT r.report_id,
   a.advertisement_title,
   COUNT(r.advertisement_id) AS total
 FROM report r
JOIN advertisement a ON a.advertisement_id = r.advertisement_id
GROUP BY r.advertisement_id')
```

Comment: Im just giving another option . This is also a way to execute query in CI.